# Can't execute Native App file in "Program file" folder from Firefox

Tags: firefox, chrome-native-messaging

I can't execute my native app from firefox if it is in `C:\Program File` folder. But when I copy it to a different place, everything is normal.

Please help me with this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Check whether you have given necessary security permissions to access the location to firefox. Problem could be caused by this.

Comment: No, I don't give any permissions for it.

Comment: I meant system permissions to that folder c:/program files
check whether yiu've given the necessary permissions